# split a value into two and then reverse the value in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a value like this `73b6424b`. I want to split value into two parts. Like `73b6` and  `424b`. Then the two split value want to reverse. Like `424b` and `73b6`. And concatenate this two value like this `424b73b6`. I have already done this like way

```
$substr_device_value = 73b6424b;
$first_value         = substr($substr_device_value,0,4);
$second_value        = substr($substr_device_value,4,8);
$final_value         = $second_value.$first_value;
```

I am searching more than easy way what I have done. Is it possible?? If yes then approach please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~^(.{4})(.{4})$~', '$2$1', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlB3ib/1)

**Details**

- `^` - matches the string start position
- `(.{4})` - captures any 4 chars into Group 1 (`$1`)
- `(.{4})` - captures any 4 chars into Group 2 (`$2`)
- `$` - end of string.

The `'$2$1'` replacement pattern swaps the values.

**NOTE**: If you want to pre-validate the data before swapping, you may replace `.` pattern with a more specific one, say, `\w` to only match word chars, or `[[:alnum:]]` to only match alphanumeric chars, or `[0-9a-z]` if you plan to only match strings containing digits and lowercase ASCII letters.